# Python TKinter: how to delete multiple widgets by the same name created in a for loop?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been trying to make a board game in Python but I was wondering how to delete multiple buttons in a for loop, as all of the buttons are called `btn` and were created in  a for loop. Currently, all it does is print each number when you click on it but I would like the bottom button to delete all of the numbered buttons. Currently, it only deletes button number 63, no matter how many times I press it. Does anyone know how I can delete all of them or use a workaround by deleting the frame or something? Here is the code which I have so far and have described.

```
from tkinter import *
from time import *
def remove():
    for x in range(0,64):
        btn.destroy()
def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("8x8 grid")
    Button(command = remove,text = "Remove all").grid(row = 8,column = 3,columnspan = 2)
    for pos in range(0,64):
        global btn
        btn = Button(command = lambda pos = pos: print(pos),width = 5,height = 2,relief = RIDGE,text = pos)
        btn.grid(row = pos // 8,column = pos % 8)
    root.mainloop()
main()
```

Thanks everyone!
(Sorry if this question has already been asked - I have not found any others that have asked the same question)

Comment: One solution would be to append each button that you create to a list. Then your can go through each button in this list in `remove` and call `destroy()` on it. Bob's your autie :)

Comment: @EriktheRed you already have the list in parent widget childs.

Comment: See question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48550578/how-to-delete-unsaved-tkinker-label/48551189#48551189

Comment: But I actually recommend Erik answer, keep names or lists with the widgets you care for.

Comment: @progmatico Yes, `winfo_children()` would work, but then you are including the button that generates the event, so you have to set up a parent frame for the buttons to remove. It works, and is probably a good idea, but rather keep it simple.

Comment: Erik's original answer works perfectly for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one option is definitely this:

```
from tkinter import *

buttons = []

def remove():
    for btn in buttons:
        btn.destroy()

def main():

    root = Tk()
    rem_btn = Button(command=remove, text="Remove all")
    rem_btn.grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan=8, sticky="ew")

    for pos in range(0, 64):
        btn = Button(command=lambda pos=pos: print(pos), width=5, height=2, relief=RIDGE, text=pos)
        btn.grid(row=pos // 8, column=pos % 8)
        buttons.append(btn)

    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Here the code is pretty self-explanatory. Store the widgets in a list, then go through it and delete each of them in the `remove` event.
As @progmatico pointed out, the `winfo_children()` approach is also doable.  This involves slightly more code...

```
from tkinter import *

def main():

    def remove():
        for btn in frame.winfo_children():
            btn.destroy()

    root = Tk()

    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

    rem_btn = Button(root, command=remove, text="Remove all")
    rem_btn.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")

    for pos in range(0, 64):
        btn = Button(frame, command=lambda pos=pos: print(pos), width=5, height=2, relief=RIDGE, text=pos)
        btn.grid(row=pos // 8, column=pos % 8)

    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Here you create a separate frame (unimaginatively called `frame`) to hold the buttons you want to delete. When the `remove` callback is triggered, tkinter goes and deletes all the children of this frame, which it gets through the `frame.winfo_children()` method.
Just watch out that you define `remove` inside of `main`, otherwise Python will not be able to reference `frame`.